# Problema ao buscar o resultado mais recente de um grupo em uma consulta em duas tabelas com PHP e MySQLi

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou estudando mysqli e PHP para migrar um blog pessoal, de PHP 5.6 para o 7 (mysql para mysqli), o blog tem uma tabela com nomes e outra com itens relacionados aos nomes, com as datas e horas, mais abaixo vou escrever um exemplo similar.

Antes, fazia uma consulta na tabela 1 e depois, ao exibir os resultados (dentro do while), colocava os códigos para uma segunda consulta, agora na tabela 2, para mostrar o item mais recente dos registros relacionados a cada nome... Estava pensando em simplificar os códigos com uma única consulta nas duas tabelas, mas não sei se será possível... pois sempre encontro problemas por não mostrar o item mais recente.

Exemplos do formato das tabelas (simplifiquei as tabelas para os estudos):

```
tabela 1 (elementos)
id,ini,nome,obs
```

```
conteudo da tabela:
1 | 200 | Elemento 1 | Livre
2 | 220 | Elemento 2 | Ocupado
```

```
tabela 2 (registros)
idtp,initp,fretp,poltp,data,hora
```

```
conteudo da tabela:
01 | 200 | 12 | 2018-06-12 | 12:11:01
02 | 220 | 10 | 2018-06-11 | 14:12:42
03 | 200 | 17 | 2018-06-01 | 10:12:31
04 | 220 | 15 | 2018-06-11 | 14:12:42
05 | 200 | 11 | 2018-06-11 | 16:15:44
06 | 300 | 16 | 2018-05-11 | 17:11:11
07 | 220 | 19 | 2018-06-11 | 14:12:42
08 | 100 | 10 | 2018-05-01 | 11:12:11
09 | 220 | 17 | 2018-06-11 | 14:12:42
10 | 300 | 11 | 2018-06-10 | 16:05:55
```

A consulta deveria pegar o ini da tabela 1 e comparar com o initp da tabela 2 e retornar um resultado initp de cada grupo com data mais recente.

Tentei esta query:

```
"SELECT tabela1.*,tabela2.*
FROM elementos AS tabela1
INNER JOIN registros AS tabela2 ON tabela1.ini=tabela2.initp
GROUP BY tabela2.initp
ORDER BY tabela1.ini DESC, tabela2.data DESC, tabela2.hora DESC"
```

Mas no resultado, não aparece o item mais recente da segunda tabela, acredito que aparece o primeiro do grupo.

Tentei usando MAX na consulta, mas dai a aparece a data mais recente, porém os demais dados do resultado não aparecem corretamente (são de outra data).

```
"SELECT tabela1.*,tabela2.*
FROM elementos AS tabela1
INNER JOIN (SELECT initp,MAX(data) As data,hora FROM registros GROUP BY initp) tabela2 ON tabela1.ini=tabela2.initp
ORDER BY tabela1.ini DESC, tabela2.data DESC, tabela2.hora DESC"
```

É possível fazer isto ou devo continuar com duas consultas ao banco de dados?
Obrigado desde já!

Comment: Consegui fazer uma query que retorna os resultados, porém ficou muito lenta, muito mais do que fazer nova consulta dentro de cada resultado da primeira consulta.

---------------------------

SELECT tabela1.*,tabela2.*
FROM elementos AS tabela1
INNER JOIN registros AS tabela2 ON tabela1.ini=tabela2.initp

WHERE tabela2.data = (SELECT max(data) FROM tabela2 WHERE initp=tabela1.ini) 

GROUP BY tabela2.initp
ORDER BY tabela1.ini DESC, tabela2.data DESC, tabela2.hora DESC

Comment: Uma solução para acelerar a velocidade seria criar uma coluna na tabela 1 guardando sempre uma referência para o valor mais recente da tabela 2, nesse caso você não necessitaria da sub-query, que vai prejudicar o desempenho do seu código